# Sharing code between client and server to remove dependency on each other

Tags: c#, oop, xna, structure

I'm developing a multiplayer game in C# and XNA that consists of a client and server project. The majority of the code is built within the **client** project (Server side validation is still being worked on) Because of this, the server executable requires the client to be within the same directory when running it. (Not a huge issue but sort of uncommon for applications) This is caused because the server (`GameName.Server`) has references to the `GameName.Client` namespace, which is within another project.

I figured the logical idea would be to separate the code into 3 parts:

1. Client (Rendering and client specific code that utilizes the "shared" project)
2. Server (Serverside logic that utilizes the "shared" project)
3. Shared/Common Code (Ex: Message types, Block types, Entity classes)

Currently (and I apoligize for the length of my question) my (simplified) structure layout is like this:

```
├───Client
│   ├───Entities
│   ├──────Player.cs
│   ├───Interface
│   ├──────Window.cs
│   ├───Networking
│   ├──────MessageHandler.cs
│   ├──────MessageType.cs
│   ├──────LoginPacket.cs
│   ├───World
│   ├──────Map.cs
│   ├──────TileTypes.cs
├───Server
│   ├───MessageHandler.cs
│   ├───Program.cs
│   ├───Other Server Stuff, etc etc
```

The server needs to be able to run a `Map` internally, which contains players and an array of blocks that it sends to clients. As you can see, it does not contain the map in it's code, it is in the client project.

The `Map` in this example, also contains rendering code to draw the map on the client (The server does not make use of these methods, yet it still uses the same `Map` class)

---

I've started creating a "shared" class library that both the client and the server make use of. Many things like message types, simple enumerations, block properties, etc. are very easy to share across projects.

My problem comes to stuff like the `Map` or `Player` classes. They both contain properties such as (In the case of a Map), a list of players. A list of players can be shared both client and server side. However, what about things like a minimap? The server really doesn't need to have a minimap, or rendering code that is only needed to display the map on the client.

How should I go about separating classes like that? My thought was to have either an interface or abstract class to handle the base (Ex: player list, current state, player positions), and have the server and client implement their own code based on what they need. (Ex: The client will implement methods to draw the map, and the server could implement methods to lookup player ID's needed for message sending)

**My question is:** How can I effeciently separate code from the client and server, so I only need to write it once, yet be able to implement custom functionality for both, without needing to depend on each other?

*I should mention the project is [open source](https://github.com/Cyral/Bricklayer/tree/master/Source), if you would like a better look at it.*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it seems like you're going down the right path in creating a shared resources library and looking towards Inheritance to solve your problem. If a class like Map or Player actually has common functionality across both client and server implementations, then an abstract class seems like the right way to go. I know I have some projects that have this kind of shared functionality which we accomplish this way.